# BTC sent to multisig address, but no info about this in bitcoin core (listsinceblock, getwalletinfo, listunspent)

Tags: bitcoin-core, multi-signature

I sent BTCs (testnet) to multisig address:

- address:     2N8yzozJh1DFgrnND7TbSbuSQ1NPA8byQDu
- transaction: 2453fe904b74acbbf541f98d2d5a1d7a509457a3df10bf38d0c3cb9326734dcd

**But my bitcoin core does not return any info about this**:

- *listsinceblock* does not print this transaction
- *getwalletinfo* returns balance 0.00000000
- *listunspent* prints nothing

Why is that? Why is this different from regular addresses? How to know that I received BTC on my multisig address?

Here are my test wallet addresses:

```
./bitcoin-cli -conf=/home/bitcoin/conf/bitcoin.conf getaddressesbylabel ""
{
  "mmqFbnqtWdXU17SkSfTWAyXMLbPRzxZRrV": {
    "purpose": "receive"
  },
  "2N8yzozJh1DFgrnND7TbSbuSQ1NPA8byQDu": {
    "purpose": "send"
  }
}
```

Is this because of the purpose of the multisig address?

---

Edit 1

I created this multisig address using *createmultisig* as I saw this in multiple tutorials. Then I realized, that my wallet does not know anything about this address, so I called *addmultisigaddress* with the same parameters. Here is the command:

```
./bitcoin-cli addmultisigaddress 2 '''
      [
        "'027f27ef1c543fdcbf4804dd79a21fe61e9d6d367cd7e13dffc58bffbd11c62732'",
        "'0362a556ffd4f6592604961d909b913a15872b605956fafb8de00e7aeb9b6ae0db'",
        "'028568c9ffc5f6e975104aa520c167bbeff80dd8a8f29905b052230fc8e15ba19d'"
      ]''' "" legacy
```

These public keys are from three separate test wallets.

Comment: How did you import/create this multisig address?

Comment: @PieterWuille I added Edit 1 with the details.